Why are U.S 10 & 20 year Treasury yields dropping sharply
The 10 year Treasury bond, and 20+ Year yield rose sharply after U.S inflation data came in inline with expectations.
On the same day though, you had the Presidential debate, and news of inflation rising in other countries around the world.
Some think a Trump presidency will be bad for inflation going up.
Bond price futures look to be strongly negative today.
Is the large rise in Treasury yields since the inflation data a sign that the market thinks inflation is on the up globally, even though inflation was inline?
Or is the fall in bond prices simply investors moving more into stocks due to the inline data and subsequent interest rate action?
Or just a range bound correction naybe?

Title: "yield dropping".  First sentence: "yield rose".  I suspect one of those should be "present value", not yield.

Long-term interest rates are a reflection of the market's expectation of the future of shorter term interest rates. They are only loosely connected with "inflation" which is more of a consumer price measure.
There's no way to give a definitive answer on why the market thinks interest rates will go down in the future. It could have to do with the upcoming election, future rate changes by the Fed, projected economic data, etc.

I see the $DJUSBK banks sector has been up on big trading volume the last two days, which also made me think about the falling yields, but banks generally do well with rising rates, so got me thinking.

Similarly, no way to tell definitively why a sector index is up - rates could be one reason, changes in regulations due to SCOTUS decision might be another.
